# Help me to find error in finding Cost Function for SSVQE algorithm

Tags: simulation, vqe, chemistry

Q: Build SSVQE's cost function using the following observable: $$O=2II−2XX+3YY−3ZZ\,.$$
This cost function should take in parameters as input. Use the included variational form, with reference states $\{|00⟩,|01⟩,|10⟩,|11⟩\}$ and weights:  $$_{00}=50\,,\\ _{01}=40\,,\\_{10}=30\,,\\_{11}=20\,.$$

- *Hint-1*: Look at the ansatz to determine how many parameters the cost function should take in.)
- *Hint-2*: Your cost function should use the `qiskit.primitives.Estimator` for evaluating all necessary expectation values

code:
[image]

[image]

the grader shows the answer is incorrect, can anyone please where i went wrong

Comment: Please do not post codes as images.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have ignored the request from Martin Vesely to use a `code` block.